# SSRS report group total mismatches

Tags: sql-server

I have a report having a main group and columns added to the group to display one row per group for the master data and no grouping for the detail data.

The group total is calculated wrong based on the detail data.

```
City    RequestID   Request Amount  ClaimID Claim Amount
El Monte    791     52,982.00       2157    41,143.75
El Monte    3691    11,838.00       3140    8,231.14
El Monte    3691    11,838.00       3141    990.00
El Monte    3691    11,838.00       3142    2,615.00
```

I have a group by City.

Each request can have multiple claims. But the request will be shown only once per row.

If there are multiple claims, then the total for the request is getting multiplied by the number of the claims.

The group total for the request amount should be 64,820 and not 88,496.

How to sum the group total by the Request Amount text box and not on the Request Amount data field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need a SQL query for this then please try the query below:

```
select 
  City, 
  SUM(RequestAmount) as RequestAmount 
from
(
  Select 
      DISTINCT City, requestID, RequestAmount 
  from tblDetails
) t
group by City
```

Here's a demo sql fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a10e/5

If you need to link back to main dataset and need a single dataset then I;d suggest a `JOIN` over City field like below:

```
select 
t1.* , t2.RequestAmount as GroupByCityRequestAmount
from 
tblDetails t1
left join 
 (
    select 
      City, 
      SUM(RequestAmount) as RequestAmount 
    from
    (
      Select 
          DISTINCT City, requestID, RequestAmount 
      from tblDetails
    ) t
    group by City
 ) t2
on t1.City=t2.City
```

See demo fiddle for this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a10e/6

Alternately you can also create a single set for grouping like this:

```
select 
   * , 
   case 
     when Row_Number() over (partition by City,requestID order by requestID) =1
     then 1 else 0 
    end * RequestAmount as GroupByCityRequestAmount
from 
   tblDetails
```

this produces an output like below

```
City        requestID   RequestAmount   ClaimID     ClaimAmount     GroupByCityRequestAmount
El Monte    791         52982           2157        41143.75        52982
El Monte    3691        11838           3140        8231.14         11838
El Monte    3691        11838           3141        990             0
El Monte    3691        11838           3142        2615            0
```

which on grouping will give correct value

demo fiddle link for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a10e/14

Comment: Should I have a separate dataset for the totals? How do I link that with the main dataset?

Comment: @DSB Which version of SQL server do you use?

Comment: @DSB updated my answer. Please check. Please do accept this as answer and/or upvote if you found it useful.